# ROC Curve having straight diagonal line at the beginning then small fluctuations

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest, roc

I am evaluating a random forest classifier model trained with old data against a recent dataset.
I understand the performance of the model should be low.
Yet, I am not sure whether this is the way the ROC should look like.
Is this ROC curve looks accurate or have I done something wrong?

I used standard scaler and fit it to the training dataset and the used the transform function to scale the test dataset.

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
df_data_test = scaler.transform(df_data_test)
```

Below are the results I got from evaluation

```
tn    158   
fp    2042  
fn    28   
tp    1072  
auc   0.507708      
macro_recall  0.974545
macro_precision   0.344252
macro_F1Score   0.50878
accuracy 0.372727
```

Any thoughts are welcomed. Looking forward to hear from you all.

[image]

Comment: Scaling the features doesn't affect a random forest at all.  What hyperparameters do you use for the forest?  Can you provide a histogram (or similar representation) of predicted probabilities?